# Variable-sized object may not be initialized

Tags: arrays, c, constants

In line 6 it appears that int variable-sized object may not be initialized, what is the problem with the int? How can i fix it?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main (void)
{
    const int SIZE=5;
    //variable remain constant
    int grades[SIZE]= {66,50,93,67,100};
    double sum= 0.0;
    int i;
    
    printf("\nMy grades are:\n");

    for (i=0;i<SIZE;i++)//0 first character and < because last character is sentinel
        printf("%d\t",grades[i]);

    printf("\n\n");
    for (i=0;i<SIZE;i++) //analyze data in list and retrieve it
        sum=sum+grades[i];
    
    printf("My average is %.2f\n\n",sum/SIZE); //sum /size for average with decimals
    return 0;
}
```

I expected to find an average using simple one-dimensional array, but that problem doesn't let me run the program

Comment: What makes you think that? Did you confirm with a debugger?

Comment: What does "doesn't let me run the program" mean in *technical terms*, such as error messages?

Comment: `int grades[SIZE]` defines a variable-length array, as `const int SIZE` is not considered a compile time expression (for defining the size of an array). A simple solution would be to change `SIZE` into a `#define SIZE 5` or an  `enum{ SIZE = 5 }`

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include more details about the problems you have with the shown code. If you get build errors, then please copy-paste (as text) the full and complete build log into the question.

Comment: Also please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Thanks @UnholySheep, it worked with enum{ SIZE = 5 }. However I still don't understant the thing about variable-length array, can you give me any resource, website, or link to the platform to understand my error? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

**`SIZE` is not a *constant*.**

`SIZE` is a `const int`, but, as strange as it sounds, it is still not a *constant*.  `grades[SIZE]` is a *variable length array*.  Variable length arrays may not be initialized.  <sup>*1</sup>

```
const int SIZE=5;
int grades[SIZE]= {66,50,93,67,100};// error: variable-sized object may not be initialized
```

---

**Alternate 1: Use a *constant***

`5` is a *constant* of type `int`.

```
#define SIZE 5
int grades[SIZE]= {66,50,93,67,100};
```

**Alternate 2: Promptly assign**

Assign or copy in the values from some source, perhaps from a *compound literal*.

```
const int SIZE=5;
int grades[SIZE];
               v-----------------------v compound literal
memcpy(grades, (int []){66,50,93,67,100}, sizeof grades);
```

---

<sup>*1</sup>
Perhaps a future version of C will allow this.

Comment: *Perhaps a future version of C will allow this.* As I have heard only pointers to VLAs will be compulsory. Automatic VLAs no.

Comment: It is even more interesting as gcc in C++ supports initialization of the VLAs

Comment: @0___________ I was also thinking of the more general idea of a `constexpr` that could allow things like `constexpr double my_pi = acos(0);` at file scope.  We'll see.